# HSM RNG - Compliance to FIPS 186-2

Tags: security, cryptography, fips, hsm

If the RNG of an HSM is said to be compliant to FIPS 140-2 (approved DRBG - SP 800-90 CTR mode) does also imply that it is compliant to FIPS 186-2 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [crypto.se] or [security.se]. If you decide to ask there, please delete the question here.

Comment: Note: The question has been reposted on [security.se] as [If a HSM RNG is FIPS 140-2 compliant, does that imply FIPS 186-2 compliance also?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/128604/2138)